# Page count disappers after the first page in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have seen that many people have this problem: the page count only appears on first page and then it disappears on the following ones. But the solutions I have seen don't seem to apply to my case because I don't have `\pagestyle{empty}` in my code.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[article, 
12pt, 
oneside, 
a4paper, 
english, 
brazil 
]{abntex2} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref} 
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\hypersetup{ 
colorlinks=true, 
citecolor=black % cor da citação. 
} 
\titulo{Title} 
\autor{Author} 
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\pagebreak

Text

\bibliography{bibliografia}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems starting the main part brings back page numbers:

```
\documentclass[article, 
12pt, 
oneside, 
a4paper, 
english, 
brazil 
]{abntex2} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref} 
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\hypersetup{ 
colorlinks=true, 
citecolor=black % cor da citação. 
} 
\titulo{Title} 
\autor{Author} 
\tituloestrangeiro{ffff}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\pagebreak
\mainmatter

Text

%\bibliography{bibliografia}
\end{document}
```